# Difference between Tables and Temp Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

why this code work without problem :

```
drop table t1 
select * into t1 from  master..spt_values
drop table t1 
select * into t1 from  master..spt_values
```

Output

```
Msg 3701, Level 11, State 5, Line 1
Cannot drop the table 't1', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

(2508 row(s) affected)

(2508 row(s) affected)
```

but this code does not :

```
drop table #t1 
select * into #t1 from  master..spt_values
drop table #t1 
select * into #t1 from  master..spt_values
```

Output

```
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
There is already an object named '#t1' in the database.
```

what is the difference between Tables and Temp Tables in this code ?

Comment: Good question. To better illustrate your point [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/5748) doesn't work, but replacing with normal tables does

Comment: [An explanation for the behaviour is here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/michael_zilberstein/archive/2008/08/28/Name-resolution-in-SQL-Server.aspx) For `t1` the statements are subject to deferred compile but this is not the case for `#t1 `

Comment: Just a s a side note "[DROP TABLE and CREATE TABLE should not be executed on the same table in the same batch. Otherwise an unexpected error may occur.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173790.aspx)"

Answer (score 4):

To counter all the other wrong answers, the correct way to test for a #temp table is

```
if object_id('tempdb..#temp') is not null
   drop table #temp;
```

---

Here's an [interesting article](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/linchi_shea/archive/2010/07/15/temp-table-name-resolution-or-maybe-not.aspx) about compile phase and execution phase fun with #temp tables.

---

This is the MSDN reference for [Deferred Name Resolution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190686%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) (DNR). To aid in Stored Procedure creation and statements batches, `Deferred Name Resolution` was added in SQL Server 7. Prior to that (Sybase), it would have been very hard to create and use tables within a batch without using a lot of dynamic SQL.

There are still limitations however, in that if the name **does** exist, SQL Server will go on and check other aspects of the statements, such as column names of table objects.  DNR was never expanded to variables or temporary (#)/(##) objects, and when inline table-valued functions were added in SQL Server 2000, DNR was not extended to them either since the purpose of DNRs were only to solve the multi-statement batch issue.  Not to be confused, **inline** table-valued functions do not support DNR; **multi-statement** TVFs do.

The workaround is NOT to use that pattern and instead create the table first and only once.

```
-- drop if exists
if object_id('tempdb..#t1') is not null
   drop table #t1; 
-- create table ONCE only
select * into #t1 from master..spt_values where 1=0;
-- .... 
-- populate
insert #t1
select * from master..spt_values
-- as quick as drop
truncate table #t1; 
-- populate
insert #t1
select * from master..spt_values
-- as quick as drop
truncate table #t1; 

-- clean up
drop table #t1;
```

Comment: @Neat If you mean in the context of the batch without `GO`'s, then yes it doesn't work to resolve the compile-time issue. I'm putting the answer up because all the other tests are simply wrong.

Comment: Is there any reason for the pooled connections stuff here? Everything I have seen online says they are dropped when the connection is reset.

Comment: Thanks @Martin. Removed the references. [This](http://www.sqlnotes.info/2012/02/01/few-things-about-pooled-connections/) is probably the most concise list I can find about sp_reset_connection